# Hide control that by default is Visible=false?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a label whose purpose is to display errors in page, so the label is not *visible* by default. I click on button "Process", which calls the button event handler. It looks something like this:

```
protected void Button_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DoComplexStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError();
        this.Label_Error.Visible = true;
        this.Label_Error.Text = ex.Message;
    }              
}
```

In the markup, the control `Label_Error` is set to `visible="false"` so whenever an error's caught, it's set to `this.Label_Error.Visible = true;` and then display the error.

The issue is that I have to *hide* it again when "Process" button is clicked. This means that at the very top of the button event handler I have to hide the label with `this.Label_Error.Visible = false;`. If not, the error will still be there when the button finishes its process.

```
protected void Button_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Label_Error.Visible = false; //Is there a way to automatically do this?
    try
    {
        DoComplexStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError();
        this.Label_Error.Visible = true;
        this.Label_Error.Text = ex.Message;
    }              
}
```

Is there a way to automatically hide a control that by default is not visible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It was inivisible by default, but because there was an error you have made it visible. Now you want to hide it again so you set it's `Visible` property to `false`. What is wrong with it? If you want to do it earlier you have to use javascript or do it in `Page_Load`.

Comment: I'm just saying that if the Form has 20 buttons and this label is used by all 20 buttons, then that means that I have to set its Visible property to false in every button.

Comment: just set the visible = false in the page load event - load event always fires and always fires before any code behind event such as for buttons etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 try
 {
    this.Label_Error.Visible = false;
    DoComplexStuff();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    LogError();
    this.Label_Error.Visible = true;
    this.Label_Error.Text = ex.Message;
 }
```

However, above is only good if that's the only button/event going on here.

I would suggest ignoring my above kluge - and move the visible setting into the page load event. it always fires first - even for button clicks and other control events anyway. So set the control in the page load event.

```
    this.Label_Error.Visible = false;
```

now any and all event code stubs are free to set the label visible = true as you have. If none do, then the control will not display. So on-load fires first and always does. I suppose, one probably should wrap above wiht a if isPostBack = False - since 99% of my pages have such code blocks in the on-load - then add above one line to your page load IsPostBack "true" code stub. But just dopping the one line above into page load will also work.